# Were missing values in data augmentation procedure parameters?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, missing-data, asymptotics, data-augmentation

Suppose I have a data set with $(Y,X)$ where $Y$ has some missing entries(say 20% missing). From $p(Y,X|\lambda)$ and prior $p(\lambda)$, I can conduct MCMC by data augmentation to impute missing $Y$'s.

Assume I have $n$ such data points. If I had no missing entries in $Y$, then according to Bernstein-von Mises theorem, $\lambda$ should be asymptotically normal as $n\to \infty$.

During data augmentation, I have to impute $Y$ by simulating corresponding $p(Y_{missing}|Y_{ob},X_{ob},\lambda)$, where $Y_{ob},X_{ob}$ are observed and $\lambda$ is given in a MCMC iteration. It seems that in this case $Y_{missing}$(missing entry) becomes a parameter to be estimated. To apply Bernstein-von Mises theorem, I need number of parameter fixed.

$Q:$ What are parameters in data augmentation? Is missing entry counted as a parameter?